# Cost functions for reducing Tensors to 1-dimensional arrays?

Tags: reference-request, tensor

I'm interested in the IT side, here, specifically how I most efficiently store a tensor in a one dimensional data structure. My assumption is that certain approaches will be more expensive than others, but I'd like to be able to validate that assumption, and show it to be wrong. Is there any work on this subject?

Comment: You need to clarify how this is related to AI, otherwise, this would be off-topic.

Comment: @nbro I hope it falls under computational aspects of AI as Tensors are mandatory for neural networks.